# Bean validation message is different between manual call and Spring MethodValidationInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I would like to use the `MethodValidationInterceptor` to trigger the bean validation. However, the error messages are different between manual calls and the `MethodValidationInterceptor`

Example manual:

```
  public void save(final Foo entity ) {
      validator.validate( entity );
   }
```

Error looks like:

```
jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException: id: must not be null
```

With Spring:

```
 public void save(@Valid final Foo entity ) {
 
 }
```

Error is:

```
jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException: save.entity.id: must not be null
```

Is there a way to remove the bean + method information from the message

Answer (score 0):

The error formats differ in validate() and @Valid annotation is because they are handled by different parts of the Jakarta Bean validation API. validate method is called by code in application, and it handles the error that are returned. @Valid annotation is handled by Jakarta Bean validation which formats the errors and return s to the application code.

The error format for Jakarta bean validation is a string that shows the constraint violation that includes property name or its value, property path that failed the validation. *"save.entity.id"* is the property path of the constraint violation.

you can create a ControllerAdvice class to handle the MethodArgumentNotValidException or BindException as below and format the error response as required.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler{

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ErrorResponse handleEx(MethodArgumentNotValidException e){
    List<String> errors = 
     e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream().map(error ->
            String.format("%s:%s", 
        error.getField().substring(error.getField().lastIndexOf('.')+1),
                    error.getDefaultMessage())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ErrorResponse(errors); }}
```

Comment: Spring is throwing a ConstraintViolationException when you use it in Spring MVC on a RestController

See MethodValidationInterceptor line 138

And then you have no chance on the Exception handler to know if it is on method level or on bean level